# Axions approaching thermal distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, dark-matter

I am reading Sikivie's paper on Axion Cosmology. I have the equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}[R^3(n_a^{th}-n_a^{eq})] = -\Gamma R^3(n_a^{th}-n_a^{eq}) \tag{1}$$
where $R(t)$ is the cosmological scale factor, $n_a^{th}$ is the number density of thermal axions, $n_a^{eq}$ is the number density of axions at thermal equilibrium, $\Gamma$ is the rate at which axions are created and annihilated.

$n_a^{eq} = \frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}T^3$, where $T$ is the temperature.

The paper says that a thermal distribution of axions is approached exponentially
fast whenever the condition $\Gamma > H$ is satisfied, where $H$ is the Hubble expansion rate. I am struggling to prove this claim.

Integrating eqn($1$), $$R^3(n_a^{th}-n_a^{eq}) = A e^{-\Gamma t}$$
where $A$ is a constant.

As time increases, I understand that $n_a^{th}-n_a^{eq}$ should approach zero, i.e., $n_a^{th}$ approaches $n_a^{eq}$, the thermal distribution. But what does $\Gamma$ have to do with $H$?